# PhoneGap www folder structure

Tags: android, cordova

My intension is to version control my www folder in my phonegap application. I am not sure if  following files/folders will have issues if I were to do that

- config.xml
- res
- spec

What are those files used for ? 
How important is the config.xml ?
Can I delete res and spec ?

Thanks !

Comment: You need them and I don't understand why you want to delete them.

Comment: I just wondering. Trying to understand more. So I guess I will go ahead and commit all of the files in WWW.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Prakash You will definately need the "config.xml" and the "res" file. The "spec" file you can safely delete as I have done and my Phonegap apps still run fine. The "config.xml" file contains important configuration settings and the "res" file contains the "drawables" folders which house your splashscreens and icon files - so you really need those.

Comment: @Prakash - No problem - glad I can be of help!